# Zend form button alignment

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I have a Zend form with two buttons, <kbd>Submit</kbd> and <kbd>Reset</kbd>. See the below form code.

```
$submit = $this->CreateElement('submit','submit')
               ->setLabel('SUBMIT');

$submit->setDecorators(
    array('ViewHelper',
          'Description',
          'Errors',
          array(
              array('data'    => 'HtmlTag'),
              array('tag'     => 'td',
                    'colspan' => '2',
                    'align'   => 'center')
          ),
          array(
              array('row'       => 'HtmlTag'),
              array('tag'       => 'tr',
                    'closeOnly' => 'true')
              )
          )
    );

$reset = $this->CreateElement('reset', 'reset')
              ->setLabel('RESET');

$reset->setDecorators(
    array('ViewHelper',
          'Description',
          'Errors',
          array(
              array('data' => 'HtmlTag'),
              array('tag'  => 'td')
          ),
          array(
              array('row'       => 'HtmlTag'),
              array('tag'       => 'tr',
                    'closeOnly' => 'true')
              )
          )
    );
```

This is my form output image:

[image]

This reset and submit button is an ugly view. I don't like this view.
How do I set the reset and submit button in the same line?

Answer (score 0):

Use `valign="top"` for both buttons.

Comment: Hi Parag, where i have use this tag 'valign' => 'top' ?

Comment: you can use same as 'align'=>'center' or if css file

Comment: can you provide  demo link. ! so i will do better

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.